# Is exponential function convex and quasi-concave?

Tags: convex-analysis, exponential-function

I am studying quasi-concave and I've come up with a question about the exponential function such as $y = e^x$. It is quite bothering me and I am wondering what have I misunderstood.
I have read several Thereom and definitions as below:

1. Every concave function is quasi-concave. Similarly, every convex function is quasi-convex.
2. A function $f$ is quasi-concave if for all $r \in\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x: f(x) \geq r\}$ is convex subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, the exponential function is a convex function. And for every r, we can find a $k$ s.t. $f(k) \geq r$, thus $\{x: x \geq k\}$ is a convex set. Thus, $f$ should be quasi-concave. But this contradict to the first Theorem. I am wondering what I am missing. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is true that the exponential function is convex *and* quasi-concave. It is also quasi-convex. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Another pointer: a function that is both quasiconvex and quasiconcave is called quasilinear, and in 1D a function is quasilinear if and only if it is monotone.